# LocationManager not working on actuall device

Tags: android

i have this problem. i am getting the location Updates. it is working fine on my emulator. but when i test it on my device it shows the current location fine. but when i change my position it do not show me updates in my location. but it is working fine on emulator.
here is my code
**Main.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {

    TextView tvStatus;
    LocationManager lm;
    boolean gpsEnabled;
    LocationListener ls = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            tvStatus.setText("Latitude: "
                    + location.getLatitude() + "\nLongitude: "
                    + location.getLongitude());
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(this, "on create", 300).show();
        tvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(this, "on resume", 200).show();
        if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            tvStatus.setText(l.getLatitude()+" "+ l.getLongitude());
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ls);
        }else{
            //use network provider
            Toast.makeText(this, "dsfdsfdsfdsf", 300).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Toast.makeText(this,"on pause" ,300).show();
        lm.removeUpdates(ls);
    }

}
```

i have added all the permisions in my manifest.xml

Comment: perhaps some logging is in order?...

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure your gps is enabled and signal is locked/fixed on actual device. if the issue still persist then initial your locationlistener in OnCreate() rather than in class.

Comment: gps is enabled. because when my app starts it shows the current location which i got by `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation()` . when i change it do not show changes. And It Works Fine on Emulator

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside a building my suggestion is not to use GPS_PROVIDER as gps doesn't work much  inside the building or takes large amount of time while taking the location fixes.